# PHP - Download and set featured image wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'am using WP trying to download image from another servee and download, and then i wan to update featured image and my script here :

```
<?php
include_once ("../wp-load.php");

$post_id = 4376;
$image_url = "https://www.sepatuonline.co.id/wp-content/uploads/raindoz/RSR-006.jpg";
update_images($post_id, $image_url);


    function  update_images($post_id, $image_url) {
$image_name = 'wp-header-logo.png'; $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$image_data = wp_remote_get($image_url);
    $image_data = $image_data['body'];
    $image_data = json_decode($image_data, true); 
$unique_file_name = wp_unique_filename( $upload_dir['path'], $image_name ); 
$filename = basename( $unique_file_name ); 
if( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) { $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename; } else { $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename; } 
file_put_contents( $file, $image_data ); 
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null ); 
$attachment = array( 'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'], 'post_title' => sanitize_file_name( $filename ), 'post_content' => '', 'post_status' => 'inherit' ); 
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id ); 
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php'); 
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file ); 
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data ); 
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
}
```

But just return broken file,  whats wrong ?

Comment: Sorry my script not beauty look because i using phone to post this question